# npm install of private package fails when package has public dependencies

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-registry

Lets say I have a private npm repository, hosted within [JFrog artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Welcome+to+Artifactory): 
 `https://my-domain.com/artifactory/api/npm/my-repo`.
In this repository I published one npm package: `my-package`, which builds fine. `my-package` has a dependency (or more) to public npm [packages](https://registry.npmjs.org)  e.g. `lodash`.

However, when I create a new project and attempt to install `my-package` I get the following error:

```sh
$ npm install my-package --registry https://my-domain.com/artifactory/api/npm/my-repo
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://my-domain.com/artifactory/api/npm/my-repo/lodash - not_found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'lodash^4.17.11' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'my-package'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-29T12_47_51_647Z-debug.log
```

It appears as though `npm` is searching within my private repository for all the dependencies `my-package` requires when I specify the `--registry` option when running an `npm install`. However, `my-package` is dependent upon public dependencies, which are not in my private registry.

**My Question**

How to install an npm package from a private registry that has public dependencies? Perhaps this is also just a JFrog issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By specifying a registry with: `--registry https://my-domain.com/artifactory/api/npm/my-repo` *npm is attempting to resolve all necessary  packages, by name and version, from your private repository location*: 
`domain.com/artifactory/api/npm/my-repo`.

To resolve these public dependencies which your private library depends upon you have two options:

1. Set up a Virtual Npm Registry. (Recommend this approach)
2. Package all necessary dependencies within your private repository.

A **Virtual Repository** defined in Artifactory **aggregates packages from both local and remote repositories.** This allows you to *access both locally hosted npm packages and remote proxied npm registries from a single URL* defined for the virtual repository.

By setting up a virtual repository which *references both your private repository location and the default public npmjs location* you will be able to download your private libraries as well as any public npm package by specifying your above mentioned registry.

Since you mentioned `JFrog` take a look at their confluence [page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Registry) which walks you through the process of creating a virtual repository.

However, if you decide to use option 2 you will have to package all the necessary dependencies within your private repository. Then your private library will be able to properly pull the dependencies it's dependent upon.  I would advise against this approach since you will be duplicating work already provided by `npmjs` and you will additionally have to keep updating your private repository to include new libraries or newer versions of existing libraries.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: There is also a third option which are [npm scoped packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope). Thats the solution that I actually came up with because it was the most suitable in my case. The only downside for me was, that I had to rename my packages to scope packages. (`@scope/...`)

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly what @ysfaran meant, but in my case I was using an `.npmrc`, and the solution was to specify the private registry address for my organizational scope using this line: `@my-org:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/my-org`. This way, within my `package.json` the package `@my-org/my-package` is the only one to be retrieved via the private registry, and all other packages are retrieved from the default public registry.

Comment: I double @Charles comment. This should be the answer as this is the most easiest way to solve the problem. Then you have your package publish with `@your-org/your-package` and can `npm install @your-org/your-package` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

### **My solution...**

involved updating my `.npmrc` file:

I changed `registry=https://npm.pkg.my-domain.com`

to `@my-private-scope:registry=https://npm.pkg.my-domain.com`

### **Here's why**

In it, I had specified that `registry=https://npm.pkg.my-domain.com` (followed by  my auth token) so that I could import a private package from the @my-private-scope scope.  However since i left at the `@my-private-scope:` part, I was changing the URL for **all** decencies, not just the ones that are part of my private organization.  I made the change to specify the my-domain URL for only the dependencies at that scope.